# SQL Server Error 26 When Using TableAdapter.FIll

Tags: sql-server, tableadapter, sql-server-2008r2-express

When I am in the Dataset Designer and I ask to Preview Data on a Fill query all is well and data is displayed.  When I try to use the TableAdapter.Fill method inside a program I get an exception for Error 26.  This code was copied down from Team Foundation Server and the Connection Strings were changed to reflect the new server.  All works fine on the old server.

I wrote another short program on the new server, added the same SQL Server Datasource and all is well, I can fill a Table Adapter.

Visual Studio Professional 2013, Sql Server Express 2008 R2, Sql Authentication in both programs.

I should also add that the code works fine in the original environment.  The TableAdapter in the Designer displays the data from the database without a problem.  It's only when I use an instance of that TableAdapter in my code that the Fill method throws an exception.  I also get the same Exception when I use the GetData Method.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is nice if you include your code as well. It will help people to help you with ease and faster as you would expect

Comment: What's the text for Error 26? If it's something like, "Cannot connect to server", then you probably have an issue with the connection string or permissions.

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified is the text of the error.  It's not a problem with the Connection String since Test Connection is successful and the data can be accessed from the Table Adapter in the Designer.  The error only occurs when I attempt to use the TableAdaper.Fill method.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

This error is related to Sql Server Connection string, check your connection string specified in web.config

1) Make sure your server name is correct, e.g., no typo on the name.

2) Make sure your instance name is correct and there is actually such an instance on your target machine. [Update: Some application converts \ to . If you are not sure about your application, please try both Server\Instance and Server\Instance in your connection string]

3) Make sure the server machine is reachable, e.g, DNS can be resolve correctly, you are able to ping the server (not always true).

4) Make sure SQL Browser service is running on the server.

5) If firewall is enabled on the server, you need to put sqlbrowser.exe and/or UDP port 1434 into exception.